# friend function can't see private member variables

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the << operator using a friend function, but it's not seeing the private member variables for some reason. Any ideas why this is happening would be quite helpful.

Here's the header file

```
    class Set
    {
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int val;
        Node* link;
    };

    Node *cons(int x, Node *p);
    Node *list;


public:
    Set() {list = NULL;}
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int size() const;
    bool member (int x) const;
    bool insert (int x);
    bool remove (int x);
    void print() const;
    const Set operator+(const Set &otherSet)const;
    const Set operator*(const Set &otherSet)const;
    Node* getSet()const{return list;}
    void setList(Node *list);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Set &set);
    };
```

Here's the function definition.

```
    ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Set &set)
    {
              Node *p;
              p = list;
              outputStream << '{';
              while(p->link != NULL)
              {
                outputStream << p->val;
                p = p->link;
              }
              outputStream << '}';
              return outputStream;
    }
```

Comment: `friend ostream& Set::operator <<`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with the accessibility of `Node` but rather with its scope: the unqualified type name does not become in scope through friendship - you should use `Set::Node` instead.

Same goes for the `list` variable: it should be `set.list`.

With these two changes in place, [your code compiles fine on ideone](http://ideone.com/TeWROz).

Comment: I actually tried this before i posted and there were problems still.

Comment: Which one of the private variables is throwing the error? The Node definition or the list? As dasblinkenlight posted, changing `Node *p;` to `Set::Node *p;` and `p = list;` to `set.list` also works for me.

Comment: It was a problem with both the Node and the list if I'm remembering correctly (don't have the code in front of me). The advice above was essentially the fix though. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

A **[simplistic representation of your code](http://codepad.org/ndbzaakM)** is:

```
class A
{
    struct MY
    {
        int a;
    };
    friend void doSomething(A);
};

void doSomething(A)
{
    MY *b;

}
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The problem lies in:

```
MY *b;
```

Your function cannot understand the type of `MY` since it is declared inside the class `A`.
Hence the error:

```
In function 'void doSomething(A)':
Line 12: error: 'MY' was not declared in this scope
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

In order to tell the function to find `My` inside `A` you need to use **fully qualified name** of the structure:

```
A::MY *b;
```

Once you do that the function knows exactly where to look for `MY` and hence can find it.
**[Working online sample](http://codepad.org/Uicac9UW)**.